# How many ways of placing two pieces on a 5x5 board?

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I'm confused because someone said the answer is $300$ but I think it is $600$.

How many possible ways of placing two pieces on a 5x5 board are there? There are no restrictions on where each piece can be put other than that both pieces cannot be in the same square.

My thinking is that the first piece can be in any of the 25 squares on the board, and the second piece can be in any of the remaining 24 squares, i.e. $25 \times 24 = 600$.

Comment: Are the two pieces "the same?"  Assuming the rows are labeled A,B,C,D,E and columns are 1,2,3,4,5... does putting a piece on B1 and on C4 count the same as putting a piece on C4 and B1?

Comment: The punchline is that the answer depends on whether the two pieces are identical or distinguishable, whether they may share a space or if they must be in different spaces.  The answer of $300$ assumes the pieces are identical and they may not share spaces.  The answer of $600$ assumes the pieces are different and they may not share spaces.  Another answer of $25^2$ would be if they are distinguishable and may share spaces.  Yet another answer of $\binom{25}{2}+25$ for if indistinguishable and may share spaces, and so on...  See more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Comment: Thank you! The pieces are distinguishable and may not be in the same square—so if the first piece is in B1 and the second is in C4, this is distinct from the first piece being in C4 and the second one in B1.

Comment: Then the answer is $600$ and not $300$.